Gromov-Hausdorff distance of equivalent metric spaces
Consider a set $X$ and two metrics $d_1, d_2$ on $X$ which are equivalent, i.e.
$$Ad_1\leq d_2\leq Bd_1 $$
on $X\times X$ for some positive constants $A,B$. Assume the metric space $X$ is compact.
What can be said about the Gromov-Hausdorff distance of $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$?
Can I get more information if I assume that $X$ is a path metric space?
Edit: There are positive answers for existence of upper bound of GH-distance in terms of the consants $A,B$ and diameter of $X$ without any additional assumptions. Up to a constant, the result is the same for any two bi-Lipschitz compact meric spaces.
I am still looking for indication on existence (or non-existence) of similar bounds from below in case that $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$ are not isometric.
Perhaps the following can be used? The Lipschitz distance between compact sets is
$$d_L(X,Y) : = \inf (|\log A_f| + |\log B_f| )$$
with infimum taken over all bi-Lipschitz maps $f:X\to Y$ with $A_f$ and $B_f$ optimal Lipschitz constants of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ respectively. If $X, Y$ are non-isometric, then this distance is not zero. Moreover if a sequence converges wrt Lipschitz metric then it converges in GH metric.
But unfortunatelly I don't see clearly a solution.

Need definition ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov–Hausdorff_convergence   Among the isometric embeddings in that definition are the ideneity maps (in both directions).  This gives us an inequality.  But to find more, we need also to know about isometric embeddings other than the identity (if any).

Identity on $X$ is in general not an isometry of $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$.

What do you think? What do you hope for? Would "it is finite" be a satisfactory answer?

I want to understand GH better principally. In this instance, two equivalent metrics give same topological structure and the point-set identitiy is naturally bi-Lipschitz. Perhaps the GH distance can be expressed in terms of the constants $A, B$ (or Gromov's dilation of identity)? This potentially can be used for convergence (non-collapsing) results for families of deformations of a metric space.

@MRH ... good point.  There are isometric embeddings into some space (say $M = X \times Y$.  Use those to get an estimate?

OK, then the answer is that all you can say is that the distance is finite, nothing else (not even an upper bound on the distance in terms of $A, B$).

@Moishe Kohan By saying "nothing else can be said" you mean it is not known or an upper bound can be shown not to exist?

@GEdgar This does not seem like a bad idea, but I'd need to get creative about it and the diameter of the set will need to appear (but it probably would necessarily appear anyways). I was hoping that something is "well-known" about GH distance of equivalent metrics.

It can be shown.

@Moishe Kohan I don't think so. I am trying to understand so I would appreciate any pointers as to why. Just off the top of my head I think one could isometrically embedd the metric space $(X,d_1)$ in the space of its Lipschitz functions, and $(X,d_2)$ in the same space. Thus the distance between the two sets would be expressed in terms of the constants $A,B$ (via the supremum norm in the function space, since $L$-Lipschitz on $(X,d_1)$ is $AL$-Lipschitz on $(X,d_2)$).

In general, suppose $d_1$ and $d_2$ are distinct compact metrics on $X$ such that the diameter of $X$ with respect to $d_1$ and let $C=\sup_{x,y\in X}|d_1(x,y)-d_2(x,y)|$.  Consider the weighted graph on vertex set $X\times\{1,2\}$ with edges between $(x,i)$ and $(y,i)$ of weight $d_i(x,y)$ and edges between $(x,1)$ and $(x,2)$ of weight $C/2$.  Let $d$ be the metric on $X\times\{1,2\}$ defined by saying the distance between two points is the infimum of the total weights of all paths between them in our weighted graph.  I claim that the restriction of $d$ to $X\times\{i\}$ is equal to $d_i$.
Consider a path in our graph between two points $(x,1)$, $(y,1)$.  By the triangle inequality for $d_1$ and $d_2$, it suffices to consider paths of the form $(x,1),(z_1,1),(z_1,2),(z_2,2),(z_2,1),(z_3,1),\dots$.  But now note that each foray like $(z_1,1),(z_1,2),(z_2,2),(z_2,1)$ into $X\times\{2\}$ can be replaced with just the edge from $(z_1,1)$ to $(z_2,1)$ without increasing the total weight, since the total weight of $(z_1,1),(z_1,2),(z_2,2),(z_2,1)$ is $C+d_2(z_1,z_2)\geq d_1(z_1,z_2)$ by definition of $C$.  Thus we may assume our path stays entirely within $X\times\{1\}$ and so its total weight is at least $d_1(x,y)$ by the triangle inequality for $d_1$.  Thus the restriction of $d$ to $X\times\{1\}$ is given by $d_1$ and similarly the restriction to $X\times\{2\}$ is given by $d_2$.
Since the Hausdorff distance between $X\times\{1\}$ and $X\times\{2\}$ is $C/2$, it follows that the Gromov-Hausdorff distance between $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$ is at most $C/2$.  In your case where $Ad_1\leq d_2\leq Bd_2$, we can say that $C\leq \max(|A-1|,|B-1|)D$, where $D$ is the diameter of $(X,d_1)$, so the Gromov-Hausdorff distance is at most $\max(|A-1|,|B-1|)D/2$.
If $A,B,$ and $d_1$ are fixed, then this upper bound is sharp.  Indeed, assuming WLOG that $|A-1|\leq |B-1|$, let $d_2=Bd_1$.  Then since the Hausdorff distance between two sets is always at least half the difference of their diameters, the Gromov-Hausdorff distance between $d_1$ and $d_2$ is at least $|BD-D|/2=|B-1|D/2$.
You can similarly get a sharp lower bound by just considering the diameters.  If $1<A\leq B$ then the Gromov-Hausdorff distance must be at least $|AD-D|/2=|A-1|D/2$ since the diameter of $(X,d_2)$ is at least $AD$, and this is realized by the metric $d_2=Ad_1$.  Similarly, if $A\leq B<1$, there is a sharp lower bound of $|B-1|D/2$ that is achieved by $d_2=Bd_1$.  (Of course, if $1$ is between $A$ and $B$ then the lower bound is $0$ since you could have $d_2=d_1$.)

Thank you! The upper bound is essentially the same as in the answer I gave earlier, but the constants are clearer and managed better. I really like the graph interpretation (first time seeing it - the paths make sense without metric space being path metric, nice)!

So i see that in general: if I have a function between two metric spaces $f:X\to Y$ and if I put $C:=\inf |d_X(x,y) - d_Y(f(x),f(y))|$, then always $d_{GH}(X,Y)\leq C/2$. If $f$ is bi-Lipschitz such that $Ad_X\leq f_*d_Y\leq Bd_X$, then $d_{GH}(X,Y)\leq \max(|A-1|,|B-1|)diamX/2$.

Yes, rescaling of a metric gives an equality to $C/2$ for the GH-distance. Yet, I was at a loss how to find a lower bound assuming $0<A<1<B$ and $A$ is attained, i.e. $Ad_X(x,y)=d_Y(f(x),f(y))$ for some $x\neq y$. It seems "obvious" there should be one in terms of the constants and diameter?

@MRH: Assuming that $A$ and $B$ are attained doesn't give you a better lower bound, since they could be attained only at points that are very close together.  For instance, let $X=[0,1]$ and modify its standard metric by stretching it by a factor of $A$ on the interval $[0,\epsilon]$ and stretching it by a factor of $B$ on the interval $[1-\epsilon,1]$.  As $\epsilon\to 0$, the GH-distance between this and the standard metric goes to $0$.

To be explicit about lower bound: GH-distance of metric spaces $X,Y$ is equal to infimum over all metrics over the disjoint sum $Z$ of $X$ and $Y$ sth on $X$ and $Y$ it is equal to respective metrcs. The above interpretation as graphs holds. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ not isometric but bi-Lipschitz with the constants $A,B$, one “only” needs to prove that the minimum of weights between $(x,1)$ and $(y,2)$ is given in terms of relation between $A$ and $B$ (admissible metrics need triangle inequality).  Seems to be equivalent to existence of lower bound on $A/B$ among all bi-Lipschitz mappings?

@MRH: I mean, if you have specific spaces $X$ and $Y$, you can't really say anything without using the details about exactly what those spaces are.  I was saying that you can't get a lower bound better than $0$ in terms of just $A,B,$ and $D$.

In your example the spaces are isometric ($X$ with itself), therefore the GH-distance is zero and attained exactly by the bi-Lipschitz map at the limit ($\epsilon=0$ represents the identity mapping which is isometry of $X$ onto itself). When two fixed metric spaces $X$ and $Y$ are not isometric, then their GH-distance is positive. I am coming to believe that if two non-isometric spaces are bi-Lipschitz, the GH-distance could be expressed by a limit on bi-Lipschitz constants (and diameter).

@MRH: For fixed $\epsilon>0$, my two spaces are not isometric (well, I guess if $A+B=2$ then they are by coincidence since the modified interval has the same length as the original one, but you can tweak the example so that they aren't).  The point is that their GH-distance can be made arbitrarily small, by making $\epsilon$ small.

Yes, for fixed $\epsilon$ the spaces are not isometric. I want to know if their GH-distance is given in terms of constants of a bi-Lipschitz map between them. The Lipschitz distance is non-zero (see edit of my question). Obviously, the Lipschitz distance between $X,Y$ is attained on bi-Lipschitz automorphisms on $X$ that factor through bi-Lipschitz maps onto $Y$. So in your example it suffices to take piece-wise linear maps to attain the distance. This suggests that there may be a lower bound for GH-distance in terms of Lipschitz distance (and perhaps something else?). Is there??

Hint: Start with the interval $X=[0,1]$ with the standard metric $d$. Now, consider two sequences of metrics on $X$,
$$
d_{1n}=nd, d_{2n}=2nd, n\in \mathbb N. 
$$
Verify that the identity map $(X,d_{1n})\to (X,d_{2n})$ is $2$-bilipschitz for every $n$ but
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} dist_{GH}((X,d_{1n}), (X,d_{2n}))=\infty. 
$$
Conclude that there is no upper bound on the GH-distance you are seeking for in terms of the constants $A$ and $B$.

So in this example the answer to the question is positive: GH-distance is given in terms of the constants.

@MRH: No, the opposite. The constants are fixed but the distance cannot be bounded from above.

One can bound the Gromov-Hausdorff distance using the constants in the equivalence and diameter, without any additional assumptions.
Without loss of generality one can assume $A=1/B$. Then identity $id: (X,d_1)\to (X,d_2)$ is bi-Lipschitz with constant $B$. Clearly, $B\geq 1$.
If $f:X\to Y$ is bi-Lipschitz with constant $B$ between two metric spaces $X,Y$, then
$$d_{GH}(X,Y)\leq (B-1)\max (diam(X),diam(Y)) .$$
Found in lecture notes https://homeweb.unifr.ch/ghanaatp/pub/gromov-hausdorff.pdf Proof is simple: consider the disjoint union $Z$ of $X$ and $Y$ with a metric
$$d(x,y):= \inf_{a\in X} (d_X(x,a)+d_Y(y,f(a)))+(B-1)D,$$
where $D$ is the maximum of diameters. The distance between $x$ and $f(x)$ is at most $(1-B)D$, since for every $a\in X$ we have
$$ d(x,f(x))\leq d_X(x,a)+d_Y(f(x),f(a)) +(B-1)D$$
and we can put $a=x$. Thus Hausdorff distance between the two isometric embeddings of $X$ and $Y$ in $Z$ is less than $(B-1)D$.
Thus
$$ d_{GH}((X,d_1),(X,d_2)) \leq B(B-1)diam(X). $$
I am posting this since comments pointed otherwise and thanks to the discussion here I stumbled upon a satisfying answer. I will not yet mark it as an answer, because still somebody could point out more interesting relations. Is there for instance a lower bound?

Note that here you are not only using $A$ and $B$ but also the diameter of $X$. This changes the question.

Yeah, already in the comments I realized that one needs to include the diameter. For one well-versed in GH-distances this would be obvious, but as I said, I just started to try to understand.

Then you should correct the first sentence in your answer since it is plain wrong and might confuse somebody else reading your question. And, as a general rule, you should edit the body of your question if you want to modify it, rather than doing so in comments.

@MoisheKohan Thank you for your input, but this answers the original question without any modification: this can be said about the relation supposing the metrics are equivalent. It is worth noting, as you did, that without diameter nothing can be said. Our discussion helped me understand the important blocks in estimates.
